# Is there a way to see all of a users posts in a given tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, questions

I'd like to link to all of my posts in a given tag or look at all the posts another user has made in a given tag. If this is possible how do I go about performing the query? If not I'd like to present this as a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, type this in the search box and press enter:

```
user:userid-of-the-prospective-user [tag-name]
```

For instance, my C# posts can be found by searching for `user:33708 [c#]`.
(for your own posts, you can simply use `user:me`)

Answer (score 6):

You can also simply click the tags on their user page, which does the same search as Mehrdad specified.

Comment: doh! *smacks forehead*